# Get at least x number of rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, rows, min

Hi I am trying to get a mysql query to work properly but to be honest Im not sure where to start, I think count function would work but not sure.

What I am trying to do is do a select but if there are less than 5 rows counted than union with another query/where clause until 5 is reached.

So basically go at least 5 rows and keep joining rows until 5 or more is reached...

```
    $myquery_mysql = mysql_query("(SELECT title, city, ad_image, rent, uniqid FROM rentals WHERE front_page_ad = '1' AND paid = '1' AND city = '".mysql_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['user_city'])."')
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT title, city, ad_image, rent, uniqid FROM rentals WHERE front_page_ad = '1' AND paid = '1' AND province = '".mysql_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['user_province'])."' )
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT title, city, ad_image, rent, uniqid FROM rentals WHERE front_page_ad = '1' AND paid = '1' )" or die(mysql_error());
```

Would I do something like...

```
            $myquery_mysql = mysql_query("(SELECT title, city, ad_image, rent, uniqid count(if title > 5) THEN FROM rentals WHERE front_page_ad = '1' AND paid = '1' )"
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT title, city, ad_image, rent, uniqid FROM rentals WHERE front_page_ad = '1' AND paid = '1' AND province = '".mysql_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['user_province'])."' ) 
    ELSE FROM rentals WHERE front_page_ad = '1' AND paid = '1' )" END ;

or die(mysql_error());
```

I know this isn't right, but I am just trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `LIMIT 5` at the end, so it will do the entire query with all the unions and then select the top 5 results, as long as you're not giving it an ORDER BY it should list them in the order you do your unions.

So if the first query has 5 results it'll just take those, but if not, it'll take results from the next 2 unions. As long as your unions aren't very time consuming this seems like a good course of action.

Comment: I was thinking of that but I need to select all the queries, so if there are 13 I need all 13, thnaks

Comment: Oh I see, my mistake. I don't know if there is an elegant way to do that. In the worst case, you could do a query first to count how many such results and if there are less than 5, you use my method, if not you just select all of the ones with your city and province.

Comment: Ah I was thinking there might not be a way to do this. My new way then I guess would be something like `code $city_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($myquery_mysql);if ($city_num_rows < 5) { //do here }` - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

- left join on using all the comparisons
- order by the comparison values `desc` so matching values order higher than non-matching (which will be `null`)
- use limit 5